# How can I require benchmark from a script loaded in Ruby C VM?

Tags: c, ruby

I have a Ruby VM set like this:

```
int ruby_state = 0;
ruby_init();

// some rb_define

rb_protect(rb_require, (VALUE)"./script.rb", &ruby_state);
ruby_cleanup(ruby_state);
```

I wanted to do some benchmarks on my C functions. I tried to add the require in `script.rb`, like this:

```
require 'benchmark'
```

And I had that error:

```
script.rb:1:in `require': cannot load such file -- benchmark (LoadError)
```

How can I require benchmark from that script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found two ways to achieve that.

## With Ruby installed

Just after `ruby_init()`, I need to add `ruby_init_loadpath()`.

```
int ruby_state = 0;
ruby_init();
ruby_init_loadpath(); // !IMPORTANT

// some rb_define

rb_protect(rb_require, (VALUE)"./script.rb", &ruby_state);
ruby_cleanup(ruby_state);
```

## Without Ruby installed

This time, it's a bit more tricky. At the beginning of the first ruby script required, we need to add this line:

```
$LOAD_PATH.unshift File.expand_path(File.join(__dir__, "/gems/"))
```

Where `"/gems/"` is the subfolder where gems are stored. Maybe it's possible to achieve that from the C api too, but it will probably be the same as in Ruby with some `rb_funcall` and `rb_intern` since the api related to load path is `static` in Ruby source.